# Creating a Oracle database connection from Eclipse but facing an issue as No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:1521/SERVICE_NAME

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, selenium, jdbc

Hi I'm facing an issue while creating an DB connection. Error which i'm getting is

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.129.135.81:1521/PROCOM1
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at CreateEndUserManagement.EndUserManagement(CreateEndUserManagement.java:50)
        at CreateEndUserManagement.main(CreateEndUserManagement.java:32)
```

Below is my code and `.classpath`

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
public class CreateEndUserManagement 
{
    static String EndUserMenu = "ctl00_HeaderMenu_MainMenun0";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException, FileNotFoundException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://example.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.name("tbxUserName")).sendKeys("test");
        driver.findElement(By.name("tbxPassword")).sendKeys("test");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Submit")).click();
        ////Calling EndUserManagement()
        WebElement enduser = driver.findElement(By.id(EndUserMenu));
        EndUserManagement(driver, enduser);
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_lnbLogout")).click();
        driver.quit();
    }
    private static void EndUserManagement(WebDriver driver, WebElement enduser) 
    {
        try
        {
                //End User Management Create Page
                Actions actions=new Actions(driver);
                WebElement Create = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Create New']"));
                actions.moveToElement(enduser).perform();                                                          
                actions.click(Create).perform();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                //DB Connection
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");            
                String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//LOCALHOST:PORTNUMBER/SERVICE_NAME";
                Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"USERNAME","PWD");
                Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();      
                Driver myDriver = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
                DriverManager.registerDriver(myDriver);     

                String v;
                //Creating Object for Test Data Excel Sheet
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:\\ExcelInputDatatoApplication\\CreateEndUserManagement.xlsx");
                Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
                Sheet s = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
                //As row count starts from 1 so initialized by adding 1 to the variable
                int rowCount = s.getLastRowNum() + 1;

                for(int i=0; i<rowCount;i++)
                {   
                    Row r = s.getRow(i);

                     for(int j=0;j<r.getLastCellNum();j++)
                     {
                         Cell c = r.getCell(j);
                         switch(j+1)
                         {

                                case 1 :    v = r.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                                            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MasterContent_ucOrg_tbxOrganizationName")).sendKeys(v); 
                                            continue ;

                                case 2 :    c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                            v = r.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                                            Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MasterContent_ucOrg_ddlWorkGroup")));
                                            sel.selectByIndex(Integer.parseInt(v));
                                            continue;

                                case 3 :    c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                            v = r.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                                            sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MasterContent_ucOrg_ddlFunctionalityType")));
                                            sel.selectByIndex(Integer.parseInt(v));
                                            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                                            continue;

                                case 4 :    c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                            v = r.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                                            sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MasterContent_ucOrg_ddlOrganizationType")));
                                            sel.selectByIndex(Integer.parseInt(v));
                                            continue;

                                case 5 :    c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                            v = r.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                                            sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MasterContent_ucOrg_ddlCountry")));
                                            sel.selectByIndex(Integer.parseInt(v));
                                            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                                            continue;       

                                case 6 :    v = r.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                                            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MasterContent_ucOrg_tbxInstallationName")).sendKeys(v); 
                                            continue ;  

                                case 7 :    v = r.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                                            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MasterContent_ucOrg_tbxAddress1")).sendKeys(v); 
                                            continue ;  

                                case 8 :    v = r.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                                            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MasterContent_ucOrg_tbxCity")).sendKeys(v); 
                                            continue ;

                                case 9 :    v = r.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                                            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MasterContent_ucOrg_tbxDistrict")).sendKeys(v); 
                                            continue ;

                                case 10 :   v = r.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                                            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MasterContent_ucOrg_tbxCounty")).sendKeys(v); 
                                            continue ;          

                                case 11 :   c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                            v = r.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                                            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MasterContent_ucOrg_tbxPinCode")).sendKeys(v); 
                                            continue ;  

                                case 12 :   v = r.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                                            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MasterContent_ucOrg_tbxTitle")).sendKeys(v); 
                                            continue ;  

                                case 13 :   v = r.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                                            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MasterContent_ucOrg_tbxFirstName")).sendKeys(v); 
                                            continue ;  

                                case 14 :   v = r.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                                            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MasterContent_ucOrg_tbxLastName")).sendKeys(v); 
                                            continue ;
                         }//End of Switch Loop 
                     }//End of For J Loop

                     //Clicking on Save Profile butt
                     driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MasterContent_ucOrg_btnSaveProfile")).click();
                     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                     //Fetches the 1st cell value from Column A till the last rows that is present in the Excel
                     v=r.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();           
                     //Storing the Test Data values in a Resultset
                     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ORGANIZATIONID FROM ORGANIZATION WHERE ORGANIZATIONNAME='"+v+"' AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE)=TO_CHAR(CREATEDDATE) ORDER BY 1 ASC");
                     //Initializing an array to the total number of rows present in the Test Data Excel Sheet
                     int[] total=new int [rowCount];
                     //Traversing and fetching the value of ORGANIZATIONID that is created from the Test Data
                     while(rs.next())
                     {
                         total[i] = rs.getInt("ORGANIZATIONID");
                     }          

                     //Update the DB for the ISACTIVE status as 1 in both the Tables
                     stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE ORGANIZATION SET ISACTIVE = 1 WHERE ORGANIZATIONID = '"+total[i]+"'");
                     stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE ORGANIZATION_ADDRESS SET ISACTIVE = 1 WHERE ORGANIZATIONID = '"+total[i]+"'");
                     stmt.executeUpdate("COMMIT");             

                     //Reinitialize drivers to Create New Profile 
                     enduser = driver.findElement(By.id(EndUserMenu));
                     Create = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Create New']"));
                     actions.moveToElement(enduser).perform();     
                     actions.click(Create).perform();
                     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }//End of For I Loop

                //Closing the DB Connection
                conn.close();
        }//End of Try Block
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }//End of Private Block
}//End of Main Class



.classpath

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Selenium Softwares/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Excel Jars/poi-3.10.1-20140818.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Excel Jars/poi-examples-3.10.1-20140818.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Excel Jars/poi-excelant-3.10.1-20140818.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Excel Jars/poi-ooxml-3.10.1-20140818.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Excel Jars/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1-20140818.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Excel Jars/poi-scratchpad-3.10.1-20140818.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Excel Jars/lib/commons-codec-1.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Excel Jars/lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Excel Jars/lib/junit-4.11.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Excel Jars/ooxml-lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Excel Jars/ooxml-lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Excel Jars/ooxml-lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Selenium Softwares + Eclipse/selenium-2.45.0/selenium-2.45.0/selenium-java-2.45.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Selenium Softwares + Eclipse/selenium-2.45.0/selenium-2.45.0/selenium-java-2.45.0-srcs.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Excel Jars/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Excel Jars/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/app/Administrator/product/11.1.0/client_1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

---

In the above code I'm trying automate the web application using Selenium and in some cases I need to create DB connection and try to run some sql statements but I'm unable to create a DB connection. I've also Configure JDBC driver in Eclipse IDE i.e ojdbc6.jar.

Please help me and do let me know if you require any other information regarding the same.

Comment: @AVD not in the buildpath. Srinidhi the jar must be added to the classpath.

Comment: I've Already built a path for my project but still i'm encountering the same error

Comment: Hey Jens i guess that classpath contains an entry for jars, can you tell me how to add the jars in the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue before and by removing // coming before localhost, problem got resolved

jdbc:oracle:thin:@LOCALHOST:PORTNUMBER/SERVICE_NAME

Comment: Hi Ashish : Even i tried the same but i'm still encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");` and `Driver myDriver = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();` are two ways of Register JDBC driver.

You have used both in your code. May be that is causing problem for you. So please try commenting out line no 50 and 51.

```
 //Driver myDriver = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
 //DriverManager.registerDriver(myDriver);
```

Hope this might help you. For more information on this you can visit this link [Ways of registering JDBC](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm)

Comment: Hi Raki : I tried it that way as well but still the issues exists

Comment: I actually have another doubt regarding the JDK version, is the JDK version 1.8 compatible with ojdbc6.jar? or is there any other way to find the compatibility for JDK 1.8 & ojdbc6.jar

Comment: After commenting out at which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Raki : I tried Commenting out the lines which you had mentioned earlier that is line no 50 & 51. When i'm tring to create a connection in that step i'm getting the error.

Comment: Srinidhi: If you are getting error at the line 47 i.e class.forName(..) then it might be bcz Ojdbc jar is missing in classpath. if the error is at line number 48 then your connection url format is wrong it should be jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port Number:databaseName    in your code it was writtten as portnumber/databasename try changing it to portnumber:databasename